# Vaadin Moving from 23 to 24 fails to find ironListConnector.js

Tags: polymer, vaadin, vaadin24

App runs fine in 23, working to update to 24.0.2.

App builds without errors but get the following errors on execution from the NetBeans IDE.

There is a long series of lines after the initial error report that I'm leaving out but can provide.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:191) ~[vaadin-spring-24.0.3.jar:na]
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

  Failed to find the following files: 
      - ./ironListConnector.js
      - ./ironListStyles.js
  
  Locations searched were:
      - `/home/white/OneDrive/Documents/Dev/hpitpc/./frontend` in this project
      - `META-INF/frontend` in included JARs
      - `META-INF/resources/frontend` in included JARs
```

Searching everywhere it seems that the ironList* files are a part of @polymer yet I am not using any @polymer stuff that I know of. And yet, the package.json includes references to @polymer:

```
{
  "name": "no-name",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@polymer/iron-ajax": "3.0.1",
    "@polymer/iron-icon": "3.0.1",
    "@polymer/iron-list": "3.1.0",
    "@polymer/polymer": "3.5.1",
    "@vaadin/accordion": "24.0.2",
...
}
```

I think these are somehow related but am at a loss on where to look for resolution.

Any help would be most welcome!

Comment: Make sure all used add-ons are compatible.

Comment: @Knoobie: Right, good steer. I have 3 components from others and have converted them all to 24.0.3 without issue. At the moment pulling everything non-standard from the app to see what falls out. Very painful.